# Make disabled feature persistent after a submit button is hit

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jsp, persistent-storage

I have a `form` with multiple drop downs and a `submit` button. Based on any choices made from `DropDown` I am disabling other drop down's but right after I hit the submit button, it refreshes the page and `set` disabled drop downs to `enabled`. How can I make those drop downs disable even after the page is refreshed.

Below is my `Script`:

```
<script>
    //Script to disable the dropdown on any selection
    var pickId;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select').change(function () {
            $this = $(this);
            pickId= $this.attr('id');
            pickValue = $this.val();
            if (pickId== 'type') {
                $('select').prop('disabled', false);
                if (pickValue == 'one') {
                    $('#parts').prop('disabled', true);
                } else if (pickValue == 'two') {
                    $('#country').prop('disabled', true);
                } else if (pickValue == 'three') {
                    $('#parts').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#country').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#today').prop('disabled', true);
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

My `JSP` Page:

```
<div id='first'>
<form id='form' method='post' action='/test/'>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="checker">

<select id="type" name="selectionOne">
    <option value="main">selection1</option>
    <option value="one">Selection2</option>
    <option value="Two">Selection3</option>
    <option value="Three">Selection3</option>
</select>

<%                       // tried to do in JSP but did not work???
    String typeChker = request.getParameter("selectionOne");
%>
<script>      // tried to do in JSP but did not work???
    document.getElementById("type").value = '<% out.print(typeChker); %>';
</script>

<select id="Parts" name="partially">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
<%
    String dur = request.getParameter("partially");
%>
<script>
    document.getElementById("Parts").value = '<% out.print(dur); %>';

    var e = document.getElementById("Parts");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
</script>

<select id="country" name="ally">
     <option value="6">USA</option>
    <option value="9">UK</option>
</select>
<select id="today" name="aty">
    <option value="123">Today</option>
   <option value="6">tomorrow</option>
</select>
<input type="Submit" Value="Submit">
</form></div>
```

After a Submit button is hit, it calls servlet to provide the response based on those selection, hence refreshes the whole `test.jsp` How do I make the disabled value persistent 
until the user doesn't change the option by itself.

Please correct me if I amd oing anything wrong and what is it I need to add to have it persistent.

Answer (score 0):

Either set a cookie in Javascript when disabling the dropdown, read that cookie on page load and disable again in Javascript. Or move the disabling into JSP and use the session.

To disable in JSP, you could do something like this:

```
<%
boolean blnOneIsDisabled =  //get from session
String oneIsDisabled = (!blnOneIsDisabled) ? "" : "disabled='true'";
%>
<select id="type" name="selectionOne" <%=oneIsDisabled%> >
```

Comment: Thank you developerwjk, so currently I have everything in my JSP file which is processign the response that a servlet would send from the request that is been posted. Could you please give any example or links through which I can learn how to make a session and proceed likewise, as I am new to JSP so trying to stick all the pieces together.

Comment: sessions are as easy as using session.setAttribute(name, value) and to retrieve session.getAttribute(name); When retrieving, however, it returns an Object, so you have to typecast: boolean x = (boolean)session.getAttribute(name); for example.

Comment: Thank you developerwjk, I did follow some quick examples, which let me save the values of any form elements into a `session variable`. But in my case, the values of that particular drop down value or text is getting persistent but not the JQuery script part. how do you guide to achieve that too via using `session`

Answer (score 0):

I am kinda confused what you are doing with the submit button, but you can try using jquery with the .on('submit"). The preventDefault() should stop it from refreshing the page.

```
$(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
     //code to run when submitting
      });
      e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you Austen, I basically have a form that one submit, it calls servlet to provide the response accordingly to my JSP page. So as soon as I choose the value and hit submit, it gives result and due to refreshment the page goes back to its previous state and the disabled feature gets enabled.Hope I answered ? our doubt